# How can I make a UISearchController start hidden?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have added a UISearchController to my code using the following method:

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = @[];
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```

This creates my search controller and adds it to the top of my tableView. Annoyingly it starts visible though:

[image]

I can hide it by sliding it up under the navigation bar which suggests the underlying functionality of the code is working but I can't get it to start hidden so I can slide it down.

I have tried adjusting the edge insets, I have tried setting the navigation bar to translucent, I have tried to go through the search bar tutorials online but nothing seems to be dealing with this issue.

Any help very welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try setting the content offset of your table view?

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.height) animated:NO];
```

Comment: I knew it was something like this, that's why I kept coming back to edgeInsets!

Answer (score 2):

Here is for swift 4

```
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: searchController.searchBar.frame.size.height), animated: true)
```

Answer (score 2):

From iOS 11.0 onwards you can use,

```
self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController;
```

The search bar will be hidden, unless you swipe down to reveal it.